# Activity Intent has an empty bundle

Tags: android, android-intent

My app has a behavior that is not consistent throughout devices.

On some devices I get this behavior:

When my app is launched from the devices "Apps" screen (the one that has all of the apps in a grid), my activity starts with an empty Bundle (meaning, getIntent().getExtras() return an object instead of null).
Launching the app from the home screen does not do that (getIntent().getExtras() returns null).

And on some devices (with the same OS version), getIntent().getExtras() returns null, no matter  what.

My Activity's launchMode is 'singleTop'.

Did anyone encounter this behavior / can think of a reason for it to happen?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Some devices were ok, but some other devices gave null execeptions.

I found if the bundle is empty, use `Intent.setExtras(b)`. Then in activity I use `getIntent().getExtras() return null;`

If I put a dummy data to bundle, the problem is resolved. `getIntent().getExtras()` never `return null;`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your post was a little hard to read so I edited it a bit. I think I might have still gotten it wrong a bit though. If you think it needs to be edited more, please [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32846955/edit) to make the answer even clearer.